# Spinner with integer array

Tags: android, integer, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create a Spinner with integers values (1, 5, 10, etc.)
I already have a Spinner with Strings and everything is working fine.

```
private static final String[] daysOfWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
Spinner spinner_days =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_days);
spinner_days.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, daysOfWeek);
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_days.setAdapter(aa);
```

When I'm trying to do the same thing with

```
private static final int[] options = {1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60};
```

then I get an error when I try to create the ArrayAdapter because I think it's only possible to do that with a String array ?

Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: All you have to do is format your integers into a string array. I do not see the problem.

Comment: because I need them to be integers, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create an `ArrayAdapter` of ints, so you could either try making a string array with numbers in it instead. Try this -

```
public static final String [] options = {"1", "3", "5", "10", "15", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"}
```

Or, you can do this using an `Integer` instead of an `int`

```
Integer[] options = new Integer[]{1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
```